# regular expression to match following characters along with matched string

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want a regular expression for below data

```
0x0040:  1402 080e 0001 0017 0300 08e0 07c1 6e54  ..............nT
0x0050:  639a 4f08 14d3 b314 0208 0e00 01a5 43    c.O...........C
0x0030:  1703 0008 e007 c16e 5463 9a30 0819 bdab  .......nTc.0....
0x0040:  1402 080e 0001 0017 0300 08e0 07c1 6e54  ..............nT      
0x0050:  639b 7908 19bd fb14 0208 0e00 0100 1703  c.y.............
```

I want to extract 16 characters starting with `e007` as shown above in bold. 
e007 will not occur together always they will be seperated by space in many paces

My expected result should be like

```
e007c16e54639a4f  
e007c16e54639a30  
e007c16e54639b79
```

Please help me with regular expression to do this.
My code is like this:

```
Dim fso,re,inFile,outFile,line,str
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp

re.Pattern = "((e0\s07)|(e00\s7)|(e007\s)|(e\s007)).{15}"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\Report.txt")
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\Result.txt", 2)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  For Each m In re.Execute(line)
    outFile.WriteLine Left(m, 24)
    If Not IsEmpty(str) Then str = str & val
  Next
Loop

If Not IsEmpty(str) Then outFile.WriteLine Left(str, 24)

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

Comment: "I want a ..." is usually a bad start for a question. We expect you to have done your own research and having tried things yourself before asking a question here. We also expect you to tell us what you have tried, so we a) don't waste our and your time by suggesting things you already ruled out, and b) may be able to find where you went wrong in your attempts. With that said, to me it's not even clear what your input data is. Do you want to extract the hex characters from the above hexdump text, or do you have a binary file from which you want to extract these values?

Comment: I tried the expression ((e0\s07)|(e00\s7)|(e007\s)|(e\s007)).{15}  But its not capturing the remaining chachter in the next line

Comment: Ansghar i forgot to convey the methods I tried. I will mention my work in future. Thank you

Comment: yes,I want to capture the Hex charachters

Answer (score 1):

Since your data appears to be a hexdump, i.e. text with a fixed width format, you may want to extract the hexadecimal values from each line and bring it into a form that allows for easier extraction of the desired values.

Assuming that you have an input file with the data from your question you could do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

data = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

For i = 0 To UBound(data)
    data(i) = Replace(Mid(data(i), 10, 39), " ", "")
Next

hexstr = Join(data, "")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "e007[0-9a-f]{12}"
re.Global  = True

For Each m In re.Execute(hexstr)
    WScript.Echo m.Value
Next
```

Comment: My code is like this 
DIm fso,re,inFile,outFile,line,str
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set re = New RegExp
re.pattern = "((e0\s07)|(e00\s7)|(e007\s)|(e\s007)).{15}"
Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\QA\Socket_sniff\feig.txt")
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\QA\Socket_sniff\Sniffer_result.txt", 2)
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
 line = inFile.ReadLine
 For Each m In re.Execute(line)
     outFile.WriteLine Left(m, 24)
 If Not IsEmpty(str) Then str = str & val
  Next
Loop
If Not IsEmpty(str) Then outFile.WriteLine Left(str, 24)
inFile.Close
outFile.Close

Comment: Ansgar I am writing the result into an txt file. there are many hex numbers repeated multiple times. any suggestion to remove the repeated hex numbers from result file.

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.